# jQuery Autocomplete with Special Characters (i.e. ö, Ä, é, or ß)

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, diacritics

How can I have autocomplete match on words with special characters, such as those in German: ö, Ä, é, or ß. For example, I'd like "mun" to match "München" and "Munchen".

Comment: Who's processing the search and returning the results? jQuery? Or some server side script like PHP/Java/etc by Ajax? If the latter, then the solution should be sought in this corner, not in jQuery corner. You have to tell more about the server side environment used then.

Comment: It's all done on the client side via jQuery using a dataset of key/value pairs loaded once on page load. The key is the ID of the item, and the value is the text I'm matching on.

Comment: That will get trickier. JavaScript has no notion about collation. Your best resort will likely be hardcoded-chararray based search and matching. I recommend to do the matching on server side using collation-aware languages or DB's.

Comment: Thanks BalusC, that's what I'll have to do. If you post that as the answer, I'll gladly mark it as correct so you get some points ;)

Comment: I have fixed it usig some functions of http://phpjs.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an excellent article on this at [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/accent-folding-for-auto-complete/) which includes some Javascript code

```js
var accentMap = {
  'á': 'a',
  'é': 'e',
  'í': 'i',
  'ó': 'o',
  'ú': 'u'
};

function accent_fold(s) {
  if (!s) {
    return '';
  }
  var ret = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    ret += accent_map[s.charAt(i)] || s.charAt(i);
  }
  return ret;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I use typeahead, and after hours of banging my head against a wall it was as simple as using utf8_encode on the script that returns the JSON:

> utf8_encode(stripslashes($variable));

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI has a demo for this problem (accent folding) on their site: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

```js
$(function() {
  var names = ["Jörn Zaefferer", "Scott González", "John Resig"];

  var accentMap = {
    "á": "a",
    "ö": "o"
  };
  var normalize = function(term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
      ret += accentMap[term.charAt(i)] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
  };

  $("#developer").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
      response($.grep(names, function(value) {
        value = value.label || value.value || value;
        return matcher.test(value) || matcher.test(normalize(value));
      }));
    }
  });
});
```