# jquery autocomplete slavian character

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have something like this

```
var availableSurnames = ["Šuber","Subertic","Sunter"];
$( "#surname" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableSurnames
});
```

What I need is that when user type S it show non only words beginning with S but all words beginning with S and Š ...

Many users haven't (or dont know how use) slavian keyboard, someone have any idea to help me?

Comment: It's interesting that the linked question has a correct answer that is only a link, which we would usually downvote.

Comment: I agree, hence I linked another one and pasted the jsfiddle into it before linking

Comment: See updated answers in the duplicates

Comment: mplungjan thi is different question: I need that when user type S the autocomplete show both S and Š

The question you linked as duplicate asked for the opposite thing
like Try typing "Jo" to see "John" and "Jörn", then type "Jö" to see only "Jörn"...

Comment: The best solution for me is this one 
https://github.com/aristus/accent-folding/blob/master/accent-fold.js

Comment: I understand your needs. This one does what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5034910/295783 - it is the code used in the github